# Hide price and popup form in selected product in category product list page

Tags: magento2, price, product-list

I need to hide price in selected product in category list page. [PFA]

[image]

I know, there are many extensions for it.

I have used 2-3 extensions for the same but it changes my theme. Because they override `list.phtml` file.

I need to change only Price `div` and add my custom code but I can't figure out how to achieve this?

**Edit**

**Before Extension**

[image]

**After Extension**

[image]

Does anyone know block name for that Price `div` ?

Comment: Are you want to hide price only from list page?

Comment: I have `dropdown` in product edit page in admin side. So price should be hide in which I have select `yes` and need to put a button instead of `Add to cart` button.

Comment: have you overrider list.phtml file in your theme?

Comment: Yes. And so when I use any other theme, it doesn't look good because of my `list.phtml` file.

Answer (score 1):

**You can set your condition based on your product value show/hide in list file,**

Your theme list.phtml file would be,
`app/design/frontend/{Packagename}/{themename}/Magento_Catalog/templates/product/list.phtml` file

Price rendering in list file using one line, `<?php /* @escapeNotVerified */ echo $block->getProductPrice($_product) ?>`

Inside **list.phtml** file

```
<?php 
    $productShow = Your condition.....;
?>
<?php if($productShow){ ?>
<?php /* @escapeNotVerified */ echo $block->getProductPrice($_product) ?>
<?php } ?>
```

Now Block file,

***function for price render is coming from block file,***

> Module-catalog/Block/Product/AbstractProduct.php

```
 public function getProductDetailsHtml(\Magento\Catalog\Model\Product $product)
    {
        $renderer = $this->getDetailsRenderer($product->getTypeId());
        if ($renderer) {
            $renderer->setProduct($product);
            return $renderer->toHtml();
        }
        return '';
    }
```

Comment: Would you please explain with more words ? I haven't more knowledge of where to create file and where to write that function `getProductDetailsHtml`.

Comment: This is default core function of magento you have to write your code inside list.phtml file of your theme.

Comment: I am creating extension and `list.phtml` file in it. I can't change  in other vendor's theme folders. At this point, design issue is occurs. One can change theme after some time, then again I have to change theme's `list.phtml` file.

Comment: you can keep above code in list.phtml of your module

Comment: That code is only for price, right ? Do I need to keep other code as it is ?

Comment: Yes this is for only price other code will remain same.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/60886/discussion-between-jigar-dhaduk-and-rakesh-jesadiya).

Comment: I have code in list.phtml file and use getProductDetailsHtml function in my block. 
Result is : Product list page is blank.
Is it good to use wrapResult function of \Magento\Catalog\Pricing\Render\FinalPriceBox ?

Comment: @JigarDhaduk please let me know whats the issue you faced?

Comment: I have used **getProductDetailsHtml** function in my block and list page is blank.

Comment: You dont need to use those function its default function of core block

Comment: Dear, then we reached at starting point. If I am using **list.phtml** in my extension, coding as per my requirement and then I apply different themes, it will take my extension's  **list.phtml** file. Theme's design was changed. Please take a look on attached image in updated question.

Comment: Please correct me if I don't understand at any point.

Comment: You can just change in your themes list.phtml file abvoe the getProductPrice($_product) line.

Comment: **Last question:** For hide price in specific product, we **HAVE TO** override whole **list.phtml** file. There is no any specific block/code that I can use in my extension by which I can override only Price **div** instead of whole list.phtml file, right ?

Comment: price div is coming from getProductDetailsHtml() this function

Comment: its better to override core list.phtml file in your theme to avoid confusions of price div.

Comment: By this, simple product's price is hide but configurable product's price doesn't hide. Any hint ?